# Qmd file in R failing to render due to `as.POSIXlt.character()` error

Tags: r

Good day everyone.

When I run the following code in my .qmd file in R it runs and provides the required gt table.

```
summary_table_lf <- load_factor %>%
   group_by(year(Date)) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean) %>% 
   rename(`Avg Load Factor (000)`= load_factor_nominal,
         `Avg Load Factor (%)`= load_fact_percent,
         `Avg Visitor Arrivals`= visitors,
         `Avg Local Arrivals`= locals) %>% 
   gt() %>% 
     tab_header(
       title = "Average Load Factor and Visitor Data",
       subtitle = "monthly"
              ) 

  summary_table_lf
```

When I attempt to render the full .qmd file I get the error below. To address this I tried `load_factor$Date<- as.POSIXlt(load_factor$Date, origin = "2014-01-01")` but that did'nt appear to work and I still got the error below. My Date column has dates in the form `YYYY-mm` and starts from 2014. How do I treat with this?

Error message:

````
Quitting from lines 103-123 [unnamed-chunk-6] (Revised-final-forecast-of-visitor-arrivals.rmarkdown)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character():
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Backtrace:
 1. base::as.POSIXlt(load_factor$Date, origin = "2014-01-01")
 2. base::as.POSIXlt.character(load_factor$Date, origin = "2014-01-01")
Execution halted
```
````

Comment: We would need to see a bit of your data to reproduce ... but one thing you can try is `anytime::anytime()` (or `anytime::anydate()` if you desire a date instead). They robustly do the right now thing with different (sane) input variants.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks. It turns out my error was related to me messing up the sequencing of when I loaded and used lubridate on my variables.